# Filtering for UI developed using GWT

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, gwt, filtering

I am developing an application using GWT as the front end technology stack. Backend stack is Struts, Spring, mybatis

We have a requirement to support column level filtering. for instance, if the client enters 'am', all words containing 'am' are filtering in the column. For GWT, to support filtering, what is the recommended approach: do we do the filtering in the front end using GWT or we develop the filtering logic in the backend and everytime the user tries to filter in the front end, we make a call to the backeng logic. Please explain pros and cons as this is a major functionality that cascades all screens.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a GWT app that supports sorting and paging of large tables. Both is done in the backend.

First, I'd say it depends on how fast your backend can handle these requests. If it's about 20ms or less per roundtrip you could do it in the backend. Another point is the upcoming amount of requests. Do you want to filter onKeyPress? So if user writes x do you start filtering instantaneously or do you start filtering after user is hitting enter?
The big pro of doing it in the backend is imho the fact that you have lightweight tablerenderer and you're not depending on how powerful the client or how old the browser is. And that's the big contra of doing it in the client as well. Some of our customers use antique browsers like IE9. I made the experience that these old browsers are pretty bad in rendering big tables and even more bad in doing some kind of live filtering.

I think at the end you need to build some testcases which are close enough to reality.

Comment: thanks mate. Also, may I ask, for the trigger for filtering, what is the common approach: do we use enter or tab out?

Comment: how about doing both? enter just executes the given filter and tab executes + jumps to the next filterable column.